# How connect authlogic and facebook in rails 3.0.9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

in my app i'm using authlogic for user logging, cart-buying etc on my shop. But how can i introduce facebook login, and goods commenting using my authlogic gem? I reed about https://github.com/kalasjocke/authlogic_facebook_connect but as i think it is for rails <3 ? is it any solution to integrate facebook first commenting, and then regestiring and loging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the omniauth gem in combination with authlogic will help you do what you're trying to do. Take a look at this [example app](https://github.com/tzumby/Authlogic-Omniauth-Rails3). [This walkthrough](http://emumair.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/social-network-authentication-with-omniauth-and-authlogic/) of how to incorporate it also looks pretty thorough.

Comment: but what to do if in authlogic i named customer, but in tutorial is user, do i need to change anything not only in migration, view, model, controller, but alsowhere? and how to rename my scaffold?